# SKSpriteNodes Colliding and sticking on top each other

Tags: swift, nodes, skspritenode

My SKSpritekit nodes are stacking on top each other and sticking to each other. I have added SKSprite nodes via the sks file and programmatically.

```
let texture  = SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cone"))
trCone = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture, normalMap: texture)
//trCone?.texture = SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cone"))
trCone?.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 65)
trCone?.position = CGPoint(x: 153, y: 267)
trCone?.zPosition = 15
trCone?.name = trainingStuff.text
trCone?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cone")), size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 65))
trCone?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
trCone?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
trCone?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = .zero
trCone?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = .zero
myTrainigArr?.append(trCone!)
self.myScene!.addChild(trCone!)

This is how I add the nodes. I would like them to overlap each other and pass through each other without any collisions but this is the outcome. When I try to move the nodes after they collide one is now stuck on top of the other. Any suggestions will be appreciated.
```

[image: Set up]

[image: When nodes collide]

Comment: It sounds like a typtical question where one doesn't know the difference between collision and contact but where he or she only calls any physical phenomenon as 'collision.'

Comment: I would just like to stop all contact between the nodes. i ideally would like the nodes to overlap or pass through each other. When they collide or make contact they appear to stick together like i shared in the picture. But this only happens with the nodes I added programmatically